# How do I eliminate the array from this object?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I'm combining two objects (`obj1` and `obj2`) with a simple function:

Obj1:

```
{ obj1-1: 'value',
  obj1-2: { obj1-2-1: 'value', obj1-2-2: 'value' } }
```

Obj2:

```
{ childs:
   [ { obj2-1: 'value',
       obj2-2: 'value',
       obj2-3: 'value',
       obj2-4: 'value',
       obj2-5: 'value' } ] }
```

The merge function:

```
// Merge objects
var merge = function(obj1,obj2) {
  var combined = {};
  for (var attrname in obj1) { combined[attrname] = obj1[attrname]; };
  for (var attrname in obj2) { combined[attrname] = obj2[attrname]; };
  return combined;
};
```

This results in the following object, `obj3`, which contains a nested array:

```
{ obj1-1: 'value',
  obj1-2: { obj1-2-1: 'value', obj1-2-2: 'value' } }
{ childs: // this is obj2
   [ { obj2-1: 'value',
       obj2-2: 'value',
       obj2-3: 'value',
       obj2-4: 'value',
       obj2-5: 'value' } ] }
```

However, I want to eliminate the nested array from the object, and want it to look like this:

```
{ obj1-1: 'value',
  obj1-2: { obj1-2-1: 'value', obj1-2-2: 'value' } }
{ obj2-1: 'value', // this is obj2
  obj2-2: 'value',
  obj2-3: 'value',
  obj2-4: 'value',
  obj2-5: 'value' }
```

Can I do this from within the merge function? The structure of the objects is always the same, so it can be a dirty solution.

---

P.s.: I've tried changing the line for `obj2` in the merge function to:

```
for (var attrname in obj2.childs) { combined[attrname] = obj2.childs[attrname]; };
```

But that returns:

```
{ obj1-1: 'value',
  obj1-2: { obj1-2-1: 'value', obj1-2-2: 'value' } }
{ "0": // this is obj2
   { obj2-1: 'value',
     obj2-2: 'value',
     obj2-3: 'value',
     obj2-4: 'value',
     obj2-5: 'value' } }
```

So I'm still not able to eliminate the `"0"` parent. When I try this:

```
for (var attrname in obj2.childs[0]) { combined[attrname] = obj2.childs[0][attrname];};
```

It returns an error: `Cannot read property '0' of undefined`

Comment: Please show the input data.  You want us to produce a function that takes some input data and creates some output data.  You show us the output format you want, but not the input data.  Are we supposed to guess what that looks like?

Comment: @jfriend00, I'm sorry, I'll include it right away!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming, you can just flatten all arrays you find at the top level of the object, you can do this:

```
// Merge objects
var merge = function(obj1,obj2) {
    function copy(src, dest) {
        for (var prop in src) {
            var item = src[prop];
            if (item instanceof Array) {
                for (var i = 0; i < item.length; i++) {
                    copy(item[i], dest);
                }
            } else {
                dest[prop] = item;
            }
        }
    }
  var combined = {};
  copy(obj1, combined);
  copy(obj2, combined);
  return combined;
};
```

Working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/95s36/

Comment: I've copied it verbatim, and it returns an error: `if (item instanceOf Array) { SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier`. The error points at the instanceOf keyword..

Comment: @Sam - I fixed a couple typos.  Working demo here: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/95s36/

Comment: Ok, your latest edit works, but still returns `obj2` with the "0" as parent.

Comment: @Sam - you grabbed it before I was done fixing it.  Working demo here: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/95s36/

Answer (score 0):

<strike>Would be helpful to know what are the initial **obj** and **obj2**.</strike> *(done)*

These two library functions might be useful for similar type of operations:

- http://api.jquery.com/jquery.extend/ (not sure if you use jQuery in your project)
- http://underscorejs.org/#flatten

---

Super quick & dirty solution, assuming array has only one object:
http://plnkr.co/edit/JN7Ptwk5VTo2IGYF7xvc?p=previewv (open console to see the result)

```
var merge = function(obj1,obj2) {
  var combined = {};
  for (var attrname in obj1) { 
    combined[attrname] = obj1[attrname]; 
  };

  // Does the array contain more objects?

  for (var attrname in obj2.childs[0]) { 
    combined[attrname] = obj2.childs[0][attrname]; 
  };

  return combined;
}
```

*(it's super quick and dirty, not really recommended but does the job for the specified input)*

*(to be more generic iterate all indices, not only the first - **[0]** - one*)

Comment: Except that neither jQuery nor underscore were asked for in the question and you don't provide a solution using either.  This seems like it should be a comment not an answer.

Comment: Good call. My intention was to provide some pointers... Good call, comment would be the right place.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I've included `obj1` and `obj2`. Does that help? I feel like I'm almost at the solution but just missing something minor...

Comment: Using underscore's flatten does not completely flatten the `obj2` btw. It returns it with the "0" as parent.